# PostgreSQL - Which film is the most popular in category “Sports”?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to answer a specific question "Which film is the most popular in category “Sports”?" 
I've tried this

```
WITH CustomerRentalsPerStore AS
(
    SELECT  R.customer_id, I.category_id,  COUNT (R.inventory_id) as rental_count 
    from    rental AS R
            INNER JOIN inventory AS I 
                on R.inventory_id = I.inventory_id
    GROUP BY customer_id, I.category_id
    --ORDER BY COUNT (R.inventory_id) desc
)

SELECT c.customer_id, c.first_name, c.last_name, cr.rental_count, cr.store_id 
FROM    Customer C
        INNER JOIN CustomerRentalsPerStore CR
            on  C.customer_id = CR.customer_id
where   cr.rental_count = (SELECT MAX(rental_count) FROM CustomerRentalsPerStore)       
 AND CR.category_id='Sports'
```

Here are the ER Diagrams:

[image: Here are the ER Diagrams]

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you

Comment: What's the issue with what you are currently using? How does it not work?

Comment: The query I'm using is for another very similar question which is "Which customer has made the most rentals at store 2?" I've just changed a few things but haven't managed to get it.

Comment: film in Sports for each customer_id?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want the film with highest number of rentals in the sports category?

Comment: @paulj no not for each customer_id, just generally.

Comment: @MartinParkin I'm pretty sure thats what they're asking, yes.

Comment: "I'm pretty sure thats what **they're asking**, yes" i noticed you said trey're asking is this homework or a job interview question? Besides without example data it's hard to suggest a query.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I meant that's what the question is asking, I'm doing this for my first job interview and I just want to do it correctly and yes I understand the concepts of this query quite well.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you clarified for me *the film with the highest number of rentals in the sports category*, I have the following *untested* SQL that should give you the result:

```
SELECT  f.title, COUNT(*) AS RentalCount
  FROM  film f
    INNER JOIN film_category fc ON fc.film_id = f.film_id
    INNER JOIN category c ON c.category_id = fc.category_id
    INNER JOIN inventory i ON i.film_id = f.film_id
    INNER JOIN rental r ON r.inventory_id = i.inventory_id
  WHERE (c.name = 'Sports')
  GROUP BY f.title
  ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

This effectively gets the number of all rentals (`COUNT`) for all films in the Sports category.  You obviously only want the first result so just limit the output to one row.

The code is untested but should point you in the correct direction.

Comment: Not sure how that's cleaner than what I have already put but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Yes this worked perfectly thank you a lot! Another thing, if I wanted to find out "which film category is the most popular among the customers" wouldn't it be really similar to the query you've shared?

Comment: @OmarKy You are welcome.  You can modify this query for that purpose too

Comment: @MartinParkin I tried modifying the query for the second question too but got lost along the way.

Comment: @OmarKy The best thing to do is to mark this question as closed and raise a new one if you have another question.

Comment: @MartinParkin I wanted to do that but it's telling me I have to wait for 90 mins to post again.

Answer (score 0):

A other approach would be to make/limit the selection as small as possible at first before going into `GROUP BY` and `COUNT(*)`processing. 
The optimizer might choose a better execution method but it will be depending on indexing.

```
    SELECT 
       film.title  
     , COUNT(*)
    FROM (
      SELECT 
        category.category_id
      FROM 
        category    
      INNER JOIN
        film_category
      ON
        category.category_id = film_category.category_id   
      INNER JOIN 
       film 
      ON
        film_category.category_id = film.film_id
      INNER JOIN
        inventory 
      ON
        film.film_id = inventory.film_id 
      INNER JOIN
        rental 
      ON
        inventory.film_id= rental.inventory_id   
      WHERE
        category.name = 'Sports'     
    ) AS alias
    INNER JOIN 
     film
    ON
      alias.film_id = film.film_id
    GROUP BY 
     film.title   
    ORDER BY
     COUNT(*) DESC
   LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thank you! What about if I wanted to find out "which film category is the most popular among the customers?"